# Proper path to place template overrides and translations for Mageplaza Blog extension

Tags: magento2.2, extensions, overrides, localisation

I recently installed [Magento 2 Blog extension FREE](https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-blog) and I want to adjust templates to suite my theme and add some translation strings.

I know that template overrides should be placed in:

```
app/design/frontend/ThemeVendor/themeName/ExtVendor_ExtName/templates
```

but I don't know what is proper path for this particular module.
I tried alot of naming conventions - small and big letters, with and without hypens - but any of them works.

Now I have:

```
app/design/fontend/Gbitdev/theme-green/Mageplaza_Magento-2-blog-extension/templates/widget/posts.phtml
```

and after any change I just copy this file to:

```
vendor/mageplaza/magento-2-blog-extension/view/frontend/templates/widget/posts.phtml
```

---

---

Second problem are translations for third-party extensions:
I cant find on web where they should be placed?
Is proper way is place e.g. `pl_PL.csv` in

```
app/design/frontend/ThemeVendor/themeName/ExtVendor_ExtName/i18n
```

or I should just add translation strings to my template translations `theme/i18n/pl_PL.csv`. Second way is not working at now becouse (I think) I don't know 4th column (e.g. Magento_Search).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Magento 2 modules you can always find the right module name in **registration.php**. So in the case of Mageplaza's module that would be `Mageplaza_Blog`.

So for your theme: `app/design/fontend/Gbitdev/theme-green/Mageplaza_Blog/templates`

As for the **translations**, you can place your csv file simply in `app/design/frontend/{Vendorname}/{themename}/i18n/` (No module name in this path).

Which means it sounds like you're doing it right. Are you clearing your cache after each change?

Comment: Yes, Yes Yesi `Mageplaza_Blog` just works ;]
 And with translations - when I just started with magento but I find it's convenient to disable cache completely - on local machine it doesn't make much performance impact.I even tried `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f pl_PL`.

Comment: Even when I added 3rd and 4th column (I have now `"Posted on %1","Utworzony przez %1",module,Mageplaza_Blog`) to follow convention from `"Sign In","Logowanie",module,Magento_Customer`  it is not working anyway.

Comment: Apologies for the delay. But you only need 2 columns. For example: `app/design/frontend/{Vendor}\{MyTheme}\i18n\pl_PL.csv` -> `"Posted on %1","Utworzony przez %1"` should be enough. Clear cache after making changes. But do note that any strings translated in the `translation` database table take preference.